# angularjs and mocha test Uncaught TypeError: (window.beforeEach || window.setup) is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, meteor, mocha.js

I have been trying to test angular js with mocha in my meteor app. I installed ngMock and have injected it to my module. I get the following issue right as I start my app.

I tried installing ngMock with both atmosphere and bower. Both shows the same issue.

`Uncaught TypeError: (window.beforeEach || window.setup) is not a function`

and after this I see throttle error in angularjs(I don't know what that means)
`Uncaught TypeError: $$rAF.throttle is not a function`

I haven't even started writing tests for angular, I just downloaded the plugin.

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

See my own question (and answer), maybe this works for you as well:

[(window.beforeEach || window.setup) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581092/window-beforeeach-window-setup-is-not-a-function/31583262#31583262)