# (window.beforeEach || window.setup) is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, phantomjs, mocha.js

I've tried to setup a testing environment with mocha, phantomjs and istanbul (and grunt). It works great so far, but when it comes to angular-testing i got some problems. I want (and need) to use angular-mocks, but as soon as I include it in my test.html, I get the following console-error in my browser:

`Uncaught TypeError: (window.beforeEach || window.setup) is not a function`

The matching code in angular-mocks.js is the following one:

```
(window.beforeEach || window.setup)(function() {
  annotatedFunctions = [];
  currentSpec = this;
});
```

This happens both for the current version (1.4.3) and for an old version which apparently worked in another project: 1.3.15.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

I fixed it.

The problem was, that i included my librarys (including `angular-mocks.js`) **before** `mocha.js` which apparently doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, your fix did not work for me, mind a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461233/uncaught-typeerror-window-beforeeach-window-setup-is-not-a-function-moch

Comment: Note: angular-mocks.js actually needs to be after <script>mocha.setup('bdd');</script> and not just after mocha.js. See Adam Brown's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461233/why-am-i-getting-this-angular-mock-error-and-mocha-test-is-not-running.