# Why am I getting this Angular-Mock error and Mocha test is not running

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocha.js, chai, angular-mock

I'm getting the **exact error as found here**: [(window.beforeEach || window.setup) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581092/window-beforeeach-window-setup-is-not-a-function/31583262#31583262). However the **fix did not work**, the [author of the tutorial series here](https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/angularjs-for-test-driven-development) even mentioned the same fix.

Here is the Tuts+ author's fix:
[image]

Which is simply to place the `angular-mock` script tag after the `Mochai` and `Chai` scripts. Which I did so below:

[image]

#### test/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Mocha Spec Runner</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="icon" href="../app/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../app/assets/imgs/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link href="bower_components/mocha/mocha.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="mocha"></div>

    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/chai/chai.js"></script>
    <!-- see Angular-mocks is here :( -->
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>

    <script>
        mocha.setup('bdd');
    </script>

    <script src="main.spec.js"></script>

    <script>
        mocha.run();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

#### My main.spec.js file

```
/**
 * @name Mocha Test Runner
 * @desc Describes and runs our dashboard tests
 */

var assert = chai.assert;
var expect = chai.expect;

// This Test is designed to fail on purpose
describe('User Login', function() {
    console.log('User Login');
    describe('Login Failed', function() {
        console.log('Login Failed');
        if ('Incorrect login should fail', function() {
            module('loginController')
            inject(function($injector) {
                apiFactory = $injector.get('ApiFactory');
            });

            expect(apiFactory).to.be.an('number');
        });
    });    
});
```

---

#### My Gulp tasks

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
    return browserSync.init({
        notify : false,
        port   : 3333,
        server: {
            baseDir: ['app'],
            routes: {
                '/bower_components' : 'bower_components'
            }
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('serve-test', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        notify : false,
        port   : 4444,
        server: {
            baseDir: ['test', 'app'],
            routes: {
                '/bower_components' : 'bower_components'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Updated my title and code. Why am I getting this error and my test is not running?

Comment: Just realized this course is from July 2015, what I don't get is, I downloaded his github repo and his tests run fine! Our app isn't using Node however, it's running via Python and Apache locally. Not sure if that has anything to do with this, but this is frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `index.html` file, you include the `angular-mocks.js` script *before* the call to `mocha.setup('bdd')`. `angular-mocks.js` is implemented as an immediately-invoked function expression which attempts to use `window.beforeEach`. (https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks/blob/master/angular-mocks.js#L2586)

However, `mocha.js` is not immediately invoked and has to be initialized with the `mocha.setup` function in order to add its magic to the runtime environment.

Try reversing the order of these script tags, so that `mocha.js` is included and initialized before `angular-mocks.js`.

```
    <script src='bower_components/mocha/mocha.js'></script>
    <script src='bower_components/chai/chai.js'></script>
    <script>
        mocha.setup('bdd');
    </script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have this part fixed already and it still happens :( sorry I must have posted older code earlier... what is driving me nuts is that the author's test totally runs lol.

Comment: Well, there goes my big idea. Perhaps you could create a git repo with your code so I could try it on my own end.

Comment: Sure! https://github.com/leongaban/test I didn't add my App files of course, but maybe you can see what's wrong here?

Comment: The code in the repo had the angular mocks script loaded before `mocha.setup()`. I switched the order around and it worked. I send you a PR just to be 100% crystal.

Comment: Ah thanks! I see now and totally miss-read, thought you mean the `run` statement, but it was actually the `mocha.setup('bdd');` :) working now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103852/discussion-between-adam-brown-and-leon-gaban).